# Ansible: passing a list of objects to a python script

Tags: python, ansible

I'm writing an Ansible role using the `script` module. The script itself is located within the role's `files` library. The environment variable `test_var` is located within a YAML file under the `group_vars` folder of the whole playbook:

```
---
- name: execute script
  script: python_script.py {{ test_var }}
  args:
    executable: python
```

This works fine and well if it's only one simple "key=value" kind of parameter, however I'm not sure how should I pass complex items like lists or list of objects to the python script to use it as a python dictionary.

Is there a best practice for this?

The Ansible role above only returns the first item of the list.

The yaml input:

```
test_var:
  - val:
      something: 1
  - other_val:
    - '1'
    - '2'
    - '3'
```

The python code:

```
import sys

i = 0

print('The first argument: ')
print sys.argv[1]
print(' ')

tmp_string = ""

print('Every argument printed out:')
for x in sys.argv:
  if i > 0:
    print x
    tmp_string += x
  i += 1

print(' ')
print('Concatenating together each argument:')
print tmp_string
```

Results:

```
changed: [localhost] => {
    "changed": true,
    "rc": 0,
    "stderr": "Shared connection to localhost closed.\r\n",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Shared connection to localhost closed."
    ],
    "stdout": "The first argument: \r\n[{uval:\r\n \r\nEvery argument printed out:\r\n[{uval:\r\n{usomething:\r\n1}},\r\n{uother_val:\r\n[u1,\r\nu2,\r\nu3]}]\r\n \r\nConcatenateing together each argument:\r\n[{uval:{usomething:1}},{uother_val:[u1,u2,u3]}]\r\n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "The first argument: ",
        "[{uval:",
        " ",
        "Every argument printed out:",
        "[{uval:",
        "{usomething:",
        "1}},",
        "{uother_val:",
        "[u1,",
        "u2,",
        "u3]}]",
        " ",
        "Concatenateing together each argument:",
        "[{uval:{usomething:1}},{uother_val:[u1,u2,u3]}]"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what to do whit the `u`s at the beginning of every line.

As I see Ansible passes every line of the yaml as a different command line argument, so the first one only contains the first line. I could concatenate these into a single string with a `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to convert that into a dictionary or something python can use.

Answer (score 2):

The easyest way to do this is

- convert list to string in Ansible
- transfer it to script
- and convert string to list in python

```
- name: Execute script
  script: "script.py {{ list_var | join(',') }}
```

```
import sys
list_var = sys.argv[1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible doesn't really provide a great mechanism for passing complex data to the `script` module. It might be simpler to write your own Ansible module, and then pass your data to it like any other module:

```
---
- name: run my module
  mymodule:
    someparameter: "{{ test_var }}"
```

Your module can be a Python script with only a little boilerplate on top of your existing code.  Here's a very simple template that would support the above example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function  # NOQA

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule


def main():
    argument_spec = {
      'someparameter': dict(type='list', required=True),
    }

    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=argument_spec,
                           supports_check_mode=True)

    result = {'changed': False}

    data = module.params['someparameter']

    # ...do something with your data here...

    module.exit_json(**result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Drop your module into the `library` directory of your role and you're all set.

You can find more information in the docs:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you need to apply a [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) to the variable. Try this:

```
---
- name: execute script
  script: python_script.py {{ test_var | to_yaml }}
  args:
    executable: python
```